# How to add any new library like spark-csv in Apache Spark prebuilt version

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have build the [Spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) and able to use the same from pyspark shell using the following command

```
bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3
```

error getting

```
>>> df_cat.save("k.csv","com.databricks.spark.csv")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/abhishekchoudhary/bigdata/cdh5.2.0/spark-1.3.1/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 209, in save
    self._jdf.save(source, jmode, joptions)
  File "/Users/abhishekchoudhary/bigdata/cdh5.2.0/spark-1.3.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/Users/abhishekchoudhary/bigdata/cdh5.2.0/spark-1.3.1/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError
```

Where should I place the jar file in my spark pre-built setup so that I will be able to access `spark-csv` from python editor directly as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

At the time I used spark-csv, I also had to download `commons-csv` jar (not sure it is still relevant). Both jars where in the spark distribution folder.

1. I downloaded the jars as follow:

   ```
   wget http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/commons/commons-csv/1.1/commons-csv-1.1.jar -O commons-csv-1.1.jar<br/>    
   wget http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/databricks/spark-csv_2.10/1.0.0/spark-csv_2.10-1.0.0.jar -O spark-csv_2.10-1.0.0.jar
   ```
2. then started the python spark shell with the arguments:

   ```
   ./bin/pyspark --jars "spark-csv_2.10-1.0.0.jar,commons-csv-1.1.jar"
   ```
3. and read a spark dataframe from a csv file:

   ```
   from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
   sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
   df = sqlContext.load(source="com.databricks.spark.csv", path = "/path/to/you/file.csv")
   df.show()
   ```

Comment: Where in your spark distro did you place these jars? Was it $SPARK_HOME/lib?

Answer (score 23):

Another option is to add the following to your spark-defaults.conf:

```
spark.jars.packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0
```

Answer (score 18):

Instead of placing the jars in any specific folder a simple fix would be to start the pyspark shell with the following arguments:

```
bin/pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3
```

This will automatically load the required spark-csv jars.

Then do the following to read the csv file:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('file.csv')
df.show()
```

Comment: How would I modify your answer when I'm setting the configuration parameters from IPython using `SparkConf().set("key", "value")` before creating the Spark Context?  I don't see a "packages" key, and setting "spark.jars" to a path containing the downloaded jar didn't work.

Comment: is there a way to do what @dnlbrky wants?

Comment: If spark context already created, you probably can't change most of it parameters.

Comment: SparkConf().set("spark.jars.packages","com.databricks:sparkcsv_2.10:1.0.3").. I know m too late to respond @dnlbrky

Comment: @Jimmy - Thanks.  This worked for me, `SparkSession.builder.config('spark.jars.packages','com.databricks:sparkc‌​sv_2.10:1.0.3' ).getOrCreate()`.  @dnlbrky @Paul

Comment: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES , Thats what im getting

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the session/context hasn't been created yet:

```
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0 pyspark-shell'
```

Comment: What if I want to add multiple packages? I am trying `--packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0 databricks:spark-deep-learning:1.1.0-spark2.3-s_2.11 pyspark-shell` but I got `Java gateway process exited before sending its port number`

Comment: @argenisleon just add comma between

Answer (score 0):

Below command helped me -: With Scala 2.10 version

```
/opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.5.2/bin/spark-shell --master local[*] --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
```

Has below dependencies -:

```
com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10;1.4.0!spark-csv_2.10.jar (2043ms)
org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.1!commons-csv.jar (419ms)
com.univocity#univocity-parsers;1.5.1!univocity-parsers.jar (1481ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

first find out the path of the spark. for example for pyspark

```
    which pyspark
```

it will return you the path for example like this- 
/home/ubuntu/bin/pyspark

then run this command by change the path as per your spark path
general-: path --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3

```
    /home/ubuntu/bin/pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3
```