# Cannot properly create a spark context in ipython to link to MySQL - com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, pyspark

I am running a local environment with Spark, PySpark, Ipython and mysql. I am strugling to be able to launch a mysql query via spark. The main issue is including the proper jdbc jar in order to be able to perform the query.

Here is what I have so far :

```
import pyspark
conf = (pyspark.SparkConf()
        .setMaster('local')
        .setAppName('Romain_DS')
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
        .set("spark.driver.extraLibraryPath","mysql-connector-java-5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar")
        .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath","mysql-connector-java-5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar")
    )
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

This is in order to properly create the spark context, and properly show the path to the jar including the jdbc driver.

Then I create an SQLContext :

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlsc=SQLContext(sc)
```

And finally the query :

```
MYSQL_USERNAME = "root";
MYSQL_PWD = "rootpass";
MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:33060/O_Tracking?user=" + MYSQL_USERNAME + "&password=" + MYSQL_PWD;
query = 'Select * from tracker_action'

dataframe_mysql = sqlsc.read.format("jdbc").options(
    url = MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL,
    dbtable = "tracker_action",
    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    user="root",
    password="rootpass").load()
```

If I run this in the ipython notebook I get the error :

> An error occurred while calling o198.load. :
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

However if I do everything from the shell (and not ipython), by initializing the spark context this way :

```
pyspark --driver-library-path './mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar' --driver-class-path './mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar'
```

It does work... I looked into the UI in Spark the configurations are the same. So I don't understand why would one work and not the other one ... Is there something to do with the runtime setting before the JVM ?

If I cannot find a proper solution, we could potentially think of running the sc in the shell and then use it from the ipython but I have no idea how to do that.

If someone can help me on that that would be great.

---- Hardware / Software
Mac OSX

Spark 1.5.2

Java 1.8.0

Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)

---- Sources to help:

https://gist.github.com/ololobus/4c221a0891775eaa86b0
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Following the comments here is my conf file :

```
# Default system properties included when running spark-submit.
# This is useful for setting default environmental settings.
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath   /Users/romainbui/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar
spark.driver.extrClassPath  /Users/romainbui/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar
spark.AppName   PySpark
spark.setMaster Local
```

--------- Solution ---------
Thanks to the comments I finally was able to properly have a working solution (and a clean one).

Step 1 : Creating a profile :

```
ipython profile create pyspark
```

Step 2 : Edit the profile startup script :

```
touch ~/.ipython/profile_pyspark/startup/00-pyspark-setup.py
```

Step 3 : Fill the file. Here I did something custom (thanks to the comments) :

```
import findspark
import os
import sys
findspark.init()
spark_home = findspark.find()

#spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
sys.path.insert(0, spark_home + "/python")

# Add the py4j to the path.
# You may need to change the version number to match your install
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip'))

# Adding the library to mysql connector
packages = "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "--packages {0} pyspark-shell".format(
    packages
)

# Initialize PySpark to predefine the SparkContext variable 'sc'
execfile(os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/pyspark/shell.py'))
```

Then you can simply run the notebook with :

```
ipython notebook --profile=pyspark
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why would one work and not the other one ... Is there something to do with the runtime setting before the JVM ?

More or less. IPython configuration you've shown executes `python/pyspark/shell.py` which creates `SparkContext` (and some other stuff) and creates a JVM instance. When you create another context later it is using the same JVM and parameters like `spark.driver.extraClassPath` won't be used.

There are multiple ways can you handle this including [passing arguments using `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33908466/1560062) or setting `spark.driver.extraClassPath` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`.

Alternatively you can add following lines to `00-pyspark-setup.py` before `shell.py` is executed:

```
packages = "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.37"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "--packages {0} pyspark-shell".format(
    packages
)
```

Setting `--driver-class-path` / `--driver-library-path` there should work as well.

Comment: Hi. Yes I am on OSX, I just updated the bash_profile with the path ... still no luck. Isn't there a way to find the location of the default conf file, I have the feeling I am not on the right one ...

Comment: I don't have OSX to test this but the last  edit should work independent of os.

Comment: Hello again. I manage to make it work by editing directly the 'shell.py' file. I am not sure if it is best practice but it works. For some reason launching the pyspark completely ignores the 'spark-defaults.conf' . I looked into the shell.py there is no line where it actually even call the 'conf' file. I could not find the 00-pyspark-setup.py file so I simply edited directly the 'shell.py' before the creation of the spark context with :
SparkContext.setSystemProperty("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/Users/romainbui/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37/mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar").

Comment: I ended up modifying the 00-pyspark which I finally found (I did not have a profile before)