# How to link PyCharm with PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm, homebrew

I'm new with apache spark and apparently I installed apache-spark with homebrew in my macbook:

```
Last login: Fri Jan  8 12:52:04 on console
user@MacBook-Pro-de-User-2:~$ pyspark
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 13 2015, 12:05:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/01/08 14:46:44 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.5.1
16/01/08 14:46:46 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/01/08 14:46:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: user
16/01/08 14:46:47 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: user
16/01/08 14:46:47 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(user); users with modify permissions: Set(user)
16/01/08 14:46:50 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/01/08 14:46:50 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/01/08 14:46:51 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.64:50199]
16/01/08 14:46:51 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 50199.
16/01/08 14:46:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/01/08 14:46:51 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/01/08 14:46:51 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/5x/k7n54drn1csc7w0j7vchjnmc0000gn/T/blockmgr-769e6f91-f0e7-49f9-b45d-1b6382637c95
16/01/08 14:46:51 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 530.0 MB
16/01/08 14:46:52 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /private/var/folders/5x/k7n54drn1csc7w0j7vchjnmc0000gn/T/spark-8e4749ea-9ae7-4137-a0e1-52e410a8e4c5/httpd-1adcd424-c8e9-4e54-a45a-a735ade00393
16/01/08 14:46:52 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/01/08 14:46:52 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 50200.
16/01/08 14:46:52 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/01/08 14:46:52 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/01/08 14:46:52 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.1.64:4040
16/01/08 14:46:53 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
16/01/08 14:46:53 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
16/01/08 14:46:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 50201.
16/01/08 14:46:53 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 50201
16/01/08 14:46:53 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/01/08 14:46:53 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:50201 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 50201)
16/01/08 14:46:53 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.1
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.10 (default, Jul 13 2015 12:05:58)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>>
```

I would like start playing in order to learn more about MLlib. However, I use Pycharm to write scripts in python. The problem is: when I go to Pycharm and try to call pyspark, Pycharm can not found the module. I tried adding the path to Pycharm as follows:

[image: cant link pycharm with spark]

Then from a [blog](http://renien.github.io/blog/accessing-pyspark-pycharm/) I tried this:

```
import os
import sys

# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/Users/user/Apps/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4"

# Append pyspark  to Python Path
sys.path.append("/Users/user/Apps/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/python/pyspark")

try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    print ("Successfully imported Spark Modules")

except ImportError as e:
    print ("Can not import Spark Modules", e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

And still can not start using PySpark with Pycharm, any idea of how to "link" PyCharm with apache-pyspark?.

**Update:**

Then I search for apache-spark and python path in order to set the environment variables of Pycharm:

apache-spark path:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-User-2:~$ brew info apache-spark
apache-spark: stable 1.6.0, HEAD
Engine for large-scale data processing
https://spark.apache.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.1 (649 files, 302.9M) *
  Poured from bottle
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/apache-spark.rb
```

python path:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-User-2:~$ brew info python
python: stable 2.7.11 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2 (4,965 files, 66.9M) *
```

Then with the above information I tried to set the environment variables as follows:

[image: configuration 1]

**Any idea of how to correctly link Pycharm with pyspark?**

Then when I run a python script with the above configuration I have this exception:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/user/PycharmProjects/spark_examples/test_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/spark_examples/test_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
ImportError: No module named pyspark
```

**UPDATE:**
Then I tried this configurations proposed by @zero323

Configuration 1:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.1/
```

[image: conf 1]

out:

```
 user@MacBook-Pro-de-User-2:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.1$ ls
CHANGES.txt           NOTICE                libexec/
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json  README.md
LICENSE               bin/
```

Configuration 2:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.1/libexec
```

[image]

out:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-de-User-2:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.5.1/libexec$ ls
R/        bin/      data/     examples/ python/
RELEASE   conf/     ec2/      lib/      sbin/
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

### With PySpark package (Spark 2.2.0 and later)

With [SPARK-1267](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1267) being merged you should be able to simplify the process by `pip` installing Spark in the environment you use for PyCharm development.

1. Go to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Project Interpreter**
2. Click on install button and search for PySpark

   [image]
3. Click on install package button.

### Manually with user provided Spark installation

**Create Run configuration**:

1. Go to **Run** -> **Edit configurations**
2. Add new Python configuration
3. Set **Script** path so it points to the script you want to execute
4. Edit **Environment variables** field so it contains at least:

   - `SPARK_HOME` - it should point to the directory with Spark installation. It should contain directories such as `bin` (with `spark-submit`, `spark-shell`, etc.) and `conf` (with `spark-defaults.conf`, `spark-env.sh`, etc.)
   - `PYTHONPATH` - it should contain `$SPARK_HOME/python` and optionally `$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-some-version.src.zip` if not available otherwise. `some-version` should match Py4J version used by a given Spark installation (0.8.2.1 - 1.5, 0.9 - 1.6, 0.10.3 - 2.0, 0.10.4 - 2.1, 0.10.4 - 2.2, 0.10.6 - 2.3, 0.10.7 - 2.4)

     [image]
5. Apply the settings

**Add PySpark library to the interpreter path (required for code completion)**:

1. Go to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Project Interpreter**
2. Open settings for an interpreter you want to use with Spark
3. Edit interpreter paths so it contains path to `$SPARK_HOME/python` (an Py4J if required)
4. Save the settings

### Optionally

1. Install or add to path [type annotations](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-stubs) matching installed Spark version to get better completion and static error detection (Disclaimer - I am an author of the project).

### Finally

Use newly created configuration to run your script.

Comment: BTW, this is how you're editing the interpreter paths, at least in PyCharm 2016:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html#project_interpreters_table
Select the "Show paths for the selected interpreter" button

Comment: On Mac version of PyCharm (v-2017.2), the Project Interpreter is under **Preferences...** instead of **File/Settings**

Comment: With option 1, how do you add Spark JARs/packages? e.g., I need com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:3.0.0-preview1

Comment: @lfk Either through configuration files (`spark-defaults.conf`) or through submit args - same as with [Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33908156/10465355). Submit args can defined in PyCharm's Environment variables, instead of code, if you prefer this option.

Answer (score 39):

Here's how I solved this on mac osx.

1. `brew install apache-spark`
2. Add this to ~/.bash_profile

   ```
   export SPARK_VERSION=`ls /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/ | sort | tail -1`
   export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/$SPARK_VERSION/libexec"
   export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
   export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
   ```
3. Add pyspark and py4j to content root (use the correct Spark version):

   ```
   /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip
   /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip
   ```

[image]

Comment: which version of pycharm is this? I am on 2016.1 community edition and I don't see this window.

Comment: 2016.1 Im on osx but it should be similar. Go under 'Preferences'. Click on your project on the left.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me on IntelliJ IDEA, which doesn't have the Project Interpreter setting.

Comment: Could you explain what adding to the content root does? I didn't need to do that... I just put the `$SPARK_HOME/python` in the interpreter classpath and added the Environment variables and it works as expected.

Comment: @cricket_007 The 3rd point: `Add pyspark and py4j to content root (use the correct Spark version)` helped me in code completion. How did you get it done by changing Project Interpreter?

Comment: @Orions I just used a virtualenv interpreter. I don't know if I tested auto-completion. I was saying that I could execute PySpark code as expected.

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! You saved me from 2 hours of desperately trying to make this work

Answer (score 13):

Here is the setup that works for me (Win7 64bit, PyCharm2017.3CE)

Set up Intellisense:

> 1. Click File -> Settings -> Project: -> Project Interpreter
> 2. Click the gear icon to the right of the Project Interpreter dropdown
> 3. Click More... from the context menu
> 4. Choose the interpreter, then click the "Show Paths" icon (bottom right)
> 5. Click the + icon two add the following paths:
>
>    \python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip
>
>    \bin\python\lib\pyspark.zip
> 6. Click OK, OK, OK

Go ahead and test your new intellisense capabilities.

Comment: Much needed answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Configure pyspark in pycharm (windows)

```
File menu - settings - project interpreter - (gearshape) - more - (treebelowfunnel) - (+) - [add python folder form spark installation and then py4j-*.zip] - click ok
```

Ensure SPARK_HOME set in windows environment, pycharm will take from there. To confirm :

```
Run menu - edit configurations - environment variables - [...] - show
```

Optionally set SPARK_CONF_DIR in environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

I used the following page as a reference and was able to get pyspark/Spark 1.6.1 (installed via homebrew) imported in PyCharm 5.

http://renien.com/blog/accessing-pyspark-pycharm/

```
import os
import sys

# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1"

# Append pyspark  to Python Path
sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.1/libexec/python")

try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    print ("Successfully imported Spark Modules")
except ImportError as e:
    print ("Can not import Spark Modules", e)
sys.exit(1)
```

With the above, pyspark loads, but I get a gateway error when I try to create a SparkContext.  There's some issue with Spark from homebrew, so I just grabbed Spark from the Spark website (download the Pre-built for Hadoop 2.6 and later) and point to the spark and py4j directories under that.  Here's the code in pycharm that works!

```
import os
import sys

# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/Users/myUser/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6"

# Need to Explicitly point to python3 if you are using Python 3.x
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON']="/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/bin/python3"

#You might need to enter your local IP
#os.environ['SPARK_LOCAL_IP']="192.168.2.138"

#Path for pyspark and py4j
sys.path.append("/Users/myUser/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python")
sys.path.append("/Users/myUser/Downloads/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip")

try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    print ("Successfully imported Spark Modules")
except ImportError as e:
    print ("Can not import Spark Modules", e)
    sys.exit(1)

sc = SparkContext('local')
words = sc.parallelize(["scala","java","hadoop","spark","akka"])
print(words.count())
```

I had a lot of help from these instructions, which helped me troubleshoot in PyDev and then get it working PyCharm - https://enahwe.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-developing-with-python-and-spark-on-hadoop/

I'm sure somebody has spent a few hours bashing their head against their monitor trying to get this working, so hopefully this helps save their sanity!

Answer (score 2):

I use `conda` to manage my Python packages. So all I did in a terminal outside PyCharm was:

```
conda install pyspark
```

or, if you want an earlier version, say 2.2.0, then do:

```
conda install pyspark=2.2.0
```

This automatically pulls in py4j as well. PyCharm then no longer complained about `import pyspark...` and code completion also worked. Note my PyCharm project was already configured to use the Python interpreter that comes with Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

## The simplest way is to install PySpark through project interpreter.

1. Go to File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter
2. Click on the + icon on top right.
3. Search for PySpark and other packages you want to install
4. Finally click install package
5. Its Done!!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-P4keLaBzc)

Assume your spark python directory is: `/home/user/spark/python`

Assume your Py4j source is: `/home/user/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip`

Basically you add the the spark python directory and the py4j directory within that to the interpreter paths. I don't have enough reputation to post a screenshot or I would.

In the video, the user creates a virtual environment within pycharm itself, however, you can make the virtual environment outside of pycharm or activate a pre-existing virtual environment, then start pycharm with it and add those paths to the virtual environment interpreter paths from within pycharm.

I used other methods to add spark via the bash environment variables, which works great outside of pycharm, but for some reason they weren't recognized within pycharm, but this method worked perfectly.

Comment: @ml_student I'll also mention that if you follow the video method (which would be my recommendation for its speed and ease) you'll need to instantiate a `SparkContext` object at the beginning of your script as well. I note this because using the interactive pyspark console via the command line automatically creates the context for you, whereas in PyCharm, you need to take care of that yourself; syntax would be: `sc = SparkContext()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup PYTHONPATH, SPARK_HOME before you launch IDE or Python.

Windows, edit environment variables, added spark python and py4j into

```
PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;{py4j};{spark python}
```

Unix,

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH};{py4j};{spark/python}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used pycharm to link python and spark. I had Java and Spark pre-installed in my pc.

These are the steps I followed

1. Create New project
2. In Settings for New Project--> I selected Python3.7(venv) as my python. This is the python.exe file present in the venv folder inside my new project. You can give any python available in your pc.
3. In settings --> Project structure --> Add Content_Root

   I added two zip folders as directories of spark

   1. C:\Users\USER\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip
   2. C:\Users\USER\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip
4. Create a python file inside the new project. Then go to Edit Configurations(in upper
   right side dropdown) and select Environment Variables
5. I used the below environment variables and it worked fine for me

   1. PYTHONUNBUFFERED  1
   2. JAVA_HOME         C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251
   3. PYSPARK_PYTHON    C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pyspark\venv\Scripts\python.exe
   4. SPARK_HOME        C:\Users\USER\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7
   5. HADOOP_HOME       C:\Users\USER\winutils

   you may want to additionally download winutils.exe and place it in the path
   C:\Users\USER\winutils\bin
6. Give the same environment variables inside Edit Configurations--> Templates
7. Go to Settings--> Project Interpreter --> import pyspark
8. Run your first pyspark program!

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/programming-guide.html#linking-with-spark):

> To run Spark applications in Python, use the bin/spark-submit script
>   located in the Spark directory. This script will load Spark’s
>   Java/Scala libraries and allow you to submit applications to a
>   cluster. You can also use bin/pyspark to launch an interactive Python
>   shell.

You are invoking your script directly with the CPython interpreter, which I think is causing problems.

Try running your script with:

```
"${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-submit test_1.py
```

If that works, you should be able to get it working in PyCharm by setting the project's interpreter to spark-submit.

Comment: *you should be able to get it working in PyCharm by setting the project's interpreter to spark-submit* -- Tried it. "The selected file is not a valid home for Python SDK". Same for `bin/pyspark`

Answer (score 0):

I followed the tutorials on-line and added the env variables to .bashrc:

```
# add pyspark to python
export SPARK_HOME=/home/lolo/spark-1.6.1
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

I then just got the value in SPARK_HOME and PYTHONPATH to pycharm:

```
(srz-reco)lolo@K:~$ echo $SPARK_HOME 
/home/lolo/spark-1.6.1
(srz-reco)lolo@K:~$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/lolo/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:/home/lolo/spark-1.6.1/python/:/home/lolo/spark-1.6.1/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:/home/lolo/spark-1.6.1/python/:/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:/python/:
```

Then I copied it to Run/Debug Configurations -> Environment variables of the script.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial from [pyspark_xray](https://github.com/bradyjiang/pyspark_xray#overview), a tool that enables debugging pyspark code on PyCharm, can answer your question.  It covers both Windows and Mac.

#### Preparation

- Open command line, kick off `java` command, if you get an error, then download and install *java* (version 1.8.0_221 as of April 2020)
- If you don't have it, download and install *PyCharm* Community edition (version 2020.1 as of April 2020)
- If you don't have it, download and install Anaconda Python 3.7 runtime
- Download and install **spark** latest Pre-built for Apache Hadoop (spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7 as of April 2020, 200+MB size) locally

  - *Windows*:

    - if you don't have unzip tool, please download and install 7zip, a free tool to zip/unzip files
    - extract contents of spark tgz file to c:\spark-x.x.x-bin-hadoopx.x folder
    - follow the steps in [this tutorial](https://medium.com/big-data-engineering/how-to-install-apache-spark-2-x-in-your-pc-e2047246ffc3)

      - install `winutils.exe` into `c:\spark-x.x.x-bin-hadoopx.x\bin` folder, without this executable, you will run into error when writing engine output
  - *Mac*:

    - extract contents of spark tgz file to \Users[USERNAME]\spark-x.x.x-bin-hadoopx.x folder
- install **pyspark** by `pip install pyspark` or `conda install pyspark`

#### Run Configuration

You run Spark application on a cluster from command line by issuing `spark-submit` command which submit a Spark job to the cluster.  But from PyCharm or other IDE on a local laptop or PC, `spark-submit` cannot be used to kick off a Spark job.  Instead, follow these steps to set up a Run Configuration of pyspark_xray's demo_app on PyCharm

- Set Environment Variables:

  - set `HADOOP_HOME` value to `C:\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7`
  - set `SPARK_HOME` value to `C:\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7`
- use Github Desktop or other git tools to clone `pyspark_xray` from Github
- PyCharm > Open pyspark_xray as project
- Open PyCharm > Run > Edit Configurations > Defaults > Python and enter the following values:

  - *Environment variables* (Windows): `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;PYSPARK_PYTHON=python;PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python;PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS=pyspark-shell;`
- Open PyCharm > Run > Edit Configurations, create a new Python configuration, point the script to the path of `driver.py` of pyspark_xray > demo_app

[driver-run-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cC2s.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Structure:

Option 1: File -> Settings -> Project: -> Project Structure

Option 2: PyCharm -> Preferences -> Project: -> Project Structure

Add Content Root: all ZIP files from $SPARK_HOME/python/lib

Answer (score 0):

For latest Spark and Python versions on MacOS as below:

```
SPARK_VERSION=3.1.1
PY4J=0.10.9
PYTHON=3.8.12
```

Adding the below environment variables for `SPARK_HOME`, `PYTHONPATH` as well as `PYENV_ROOT` to `~/.bash_profile`. In addition, `SPARK_HOME` and `PYENV_ROOT` being added to `PATH`.

```
export SPARK_VERSION=`ls /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/ | sort | tail -1`
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/$SPARK_VERSION/libexec
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH

export PYENV_ROOT=/usr/local/opt/pyenv
export PATH=$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Under `Project -> Preferences -> Python Interpreter`, add the PyEnv Python as a new Interpreter and use it instead of the default interpreter.

Under Add Python Interpreter, go to `Virtual Environment -> Under Existing Environment` -> select `/usr/local/opt/pyenv/versions/3.8.12/bin/python` as the Python interpreter for the PySpark project.

In the Python code, add the below code block at the beginning (NOTE: `pyspark`, `findspark` and `py4j` needs to be installed as packages beforehead)

```
import findspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
findspark.init("/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.1.1/libexec")
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is

> Go to the site-packages folder of your anaconda/python installation, Copy paste the **pyspark** and **pyspark.egg-info** folders there.

Restart pycharm to update index.
The above mentioned two folders are present in spark/python folder of your spark installation. This way you'll get code completion suggestions also from pycharm.

> The site-packages can be easily found in your python installation. In anaconda its under **anaconda/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages**

Comment: This way pycharm will think its another lib.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to add the pyspark module via Project Interpreter menu but was not enough... there are a number of system environment variables that need to be set like `SPARK_HOME` and a path to `/hadoop/bin/winutils.exe` in order to read local data files.  You also need to be using correct versions of Python, JRE, JDK all available in system environment variables and `PATH`.  After googling a lot, the [instructions in these videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf0swTFhTI8pYbd8mr36LiYIOOY2xw5Iu) **worked**