# working on pyspark from pycharm

Tags: apache-spark, pycharm, pyspark

I am trying to create some scripts for pyspark using pycharm.
While I found multiple explanation on how to connect them (such as [How to link PyCharm with PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark)) not everything works properly.

What I did is basically set the environment variables correctly:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH 
:/usr/local/spark/python:/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip
echo $SPARK_HOME 
/usr/local/spark
```

and in the code I have:

```
appName = "demo1"
master = "local"
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

The problem is that many dataframe aggregation functions appear as errors. For example I have the following lines:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as agg_funcs
maxTimeStamp = base_df.agg(agg_funcs.max(base_df.time)).collect()
```

Yet pycharm claims: Cannot find reference 'max' in functions.py
A similar error apepars for most aggregate functions (e.g. col, count)

How would I fix this?

Comment: This is still true in version 1.6.1

Comment: Still true with latest PySpark and latest PyCharm! See the issue linked below :/

Comment: you can try https://medium.com/@gauravmshah/pyspark-on-intellij-with-packages-auto-complete-5e3208504707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the limitation of python analysis in pycharm. Since pyspark generates some of its function on the fly. I have actually opened an issue with pycharm (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20200). which provides some solutions which is basically to write some interface code manually.

**Update**:

If you look at [this thread](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/PYTHON-PySpark-typing-hints-td21560.html) you can see some advancement in the topic. [This](https://github.com/zero323/pyspark-stubs) has a working interface for most stuff and [here](https://speakerdeck.com/marcobonzanini/static-type-analysis-for-robust-data-products-at-pydata-london-2017) is some more info on it.

Answer (score 2):

pycharm -> settings -> project -> Project structure -> add root content

select the following path from spark installation folder

1. spark/python/lib/py4j....sr.zip
2. spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip

Answer (score 0):

Writing scripts in PyCharm is great, but for running them I advise you to use the `spark-submit`  command right from the console to execute them.

If you really want to run them straight from PyCharm there is a great github project called [findspark](https://github.com/minrk/findspark) which allows you to do just what you are asking for.

Install the library and just add to the top of your code

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
```

The rest of the code goes just below that and findspark will do all of the job for you!

Comment: The problem is not writing the code but rather the IDE itself not recognizing functions.