# Running pyspark program in pycharm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning spark and stuck at running the sample basic program the word count. Please help in resolving this

I am using pycharm and my Os is windows

Here is the code I am using

```
import os
import sys

# Path for folder containing winutils.exe . Without it I was getting the error java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME']="C:\\Users\\ekhaavi\\Documents\\ApacheSpark\\Hadoop"
# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="C:\\Users\ekhaavi\\Documents\\ApacheSpark\\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6"
# Append to PYTHONPATH so that pyspark could be found
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\ekhaavi\\Documents\\ApacheSpark\\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\\python")
#this is to overcome the py4j exception
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\ekhaavi\\Documents\\ApacheSpark\\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\\python\\lib\\py4j-0.9-src.zip")

# Now we are ready to import Spark Modules
try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf

except ImportError as e:
    print ("Error importing Spark Modules", e)
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext('local')
    words = sc.parallelize(["scala","java","hadoop","spark","akka"])
    print(words.count())
```

After running I am getting the below Exceptions

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:139)
    ... 11 more
16/03/03 14:40:55 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:139)
    ... 11 more

16/03/03 14:40:55 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/03/03 14:40:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/03/03 14:40:55 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
16/03/03 14:40:55 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (count at C:/Users/ekhaavi/PycharmProjects/FileProcessingStream/FileProcessingStream.py:32) failed in 0.539 s
16/03/03 14:40:55 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: count at C:/Users/ekhaavi/PycharmProjects/FileProcessingStream/FileProcessingStream.py:32, took 0.854514 s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ekhaavi/PycharmProjects/FileProcessingStream/FileProcessingStream.py", line 32, in <module>
    print(words.count())
  File "C:\Users\ekhaavi\Documents\ApacheSpark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1004, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "C:\Users\ekhaavi\Documents\ApacheSpark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 995, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "C:\Users\ekhaavi\Documents\ApacheSpark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 869, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "C:\Users\ekhaavi\Documents\ApacheSpark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "C:\Users\ekhaavi\Documents\ApacheSpark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
  File "C:\Users\ekhaavi\Documents\ApacheSpark\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:139)
    ... 11 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:139)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link PyCharm with PySpark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark)

Comment: To overcome this we have to download the “winutils.exe” from ”

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/28a57efb- 082b-424b- 8d9e-

731b1fe135de/please-read- if-experiencing- job-failures?forum=hdinsight”

After downloading the file put it in a Directory/bin and defines that Directory to HADOOP_HOME under

windows environment variable. This fixes the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome this we have to download the “winutils.exe” from ”

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/28a57efb- 082b-424b- 8d9e-

731b1fe135de/please-read- if-experiencing- job-failures?forum=hdinsight”

After downloading the file put it in a Directory/bin and defines that Directory to HADOOP_HOME under

windows environment variable

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. After a long struggle with exception messages, I fixed it with winutils.