# pycharm: How do I import pyspark to pycharm

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, virtualenv, pyspark

I have done quite some spark job in Java/Scala, where I can run some test spark job directly from main() program, as long as I add the required spark jar in the maven pom.xml.

Now I am starting to work with pyspark. I am wondering if I could do something similar? For example, I am using pycharm to run a the wordCount job:

[image]

If I just run the main() program, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/profiler/run_profiler.py", line 145, in <module>
    profiler.run(file)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/profiler/run_profiler.py", line 84, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, globals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/edamame/PycharmProjects/myWordCount/myWordCount.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkContext
ImportError: No module named pyspark

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am wondering how do I import pyspark here? so I could run some test job from the main() program like I did in Java/Scala.

I also tried to edit the interpreter path:
[image]

and my screenshot from Run -> Edit Configuration:

[image]

Last is my project structure screen shot:
[image]

Did I miss anything here? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are missing the pyspark module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link PyCharm with PySpark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark)

Comment: @cricket_007: I have modified my question above. I tried to "Edit interpreter paths so it contains path to $SPARK_HOME/python" as mentioned in "How to link PyCharm with PySpark?", but I can't find where to edit the interpreter path ... am I missing anything here? thanks

Comment: Have you followed the possible dupe?

Comment: Yes, it asked me to edit the interpreter path, but I don't see such option ...

Comment: I think you are in the wrong settings window. You need to go from the Run Window Menu, then Edit Configuration, and there you can edit the Environment Variables and Interpreter and whatnot

Comment: I got this working in IntelliJ (also, I read the other answers on that post), here is my "interpreter settings" window with the highlighted line I added. http://i.stack.imgur.com/iltzW.png

Comment: mmm ... I am using the free pyCharm community version. Could that be a problem? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't matter. I just use the community version of IntelliJ IDEA with the Pycharm plugin because I also do Android, Scala, and Java coding.

Comment: I just add a screenshot above for my Run -> Edit Configuration, where can I modify interpreter path there? Thanks

Comment: You modify the interpreter path in the first settings window you show (look in Project Structure, maybe. Intellij doesn't have the settings you show). You **add** the `SPARK_HOME` and `PYTHONPATH` **environment variables** in the second window you added.

Comment: Thanks. I also added the Project Structure screenshot ... the only place I can add is root content, but doesn't seem to work. Is IntelliJ with Pycharm plugin better than PyCharm? Should I actually use IntelliJ ... as I couldn't even do such a simple configuration in Pycharm ...

Comment: This post helped me. Though, as you said, you work with Java/Scala, so I don't see why you need plain PyCharm when IntelliJ IDEA works fine with python projects. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36415945/2308683

Comment: It just I have used Eclipse for Java/Scala for years, and it works very well. Since Eclipse is free, I don't know if the IntelliJ free community version could work as good as Eclipse and would the free version lack any functionality. Do you have all you needs in the IntelliJ free community version? Thanks!

Comment: I started with Eclipse, but moved to the community version of IntellIj a few years back, and it works for my needs. Can't do Java EE or database connections without paying for IntelliJ, there are free other ways around that. If you like PyCharm for Python, then any Java/Scala work in IntelliJ would be very similar.

Comment: probably this would help https://medium.com/@gauravmshah/pyspark-on-intellij-with-packages-auto-complete-5e3208504707

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it work following the steps in this post. It is really helpful!

https://medium.com/data-science-cafe/pycharm-and-apache-spark-on-mac-os-x-990af6dc6f38#.jk5hl4kz0

Answer (score 1):

I added the py4j-x.x.x-src.zip and pyspark.zip under $SPARK_HOME/python/lib to the project structure (preferences > Project> Project Structure and then do "+ Add Content Root") and it worked fine.

PS: Pycharm already had $PYTHONPATH and $SPARK_HOME read from the os env, which was set in .bashrc/.bash_profile

Comment: This is the one that worked for me on pycharm `2019.2`