# Can Intellij python interpreter be set to a virtualenv like in pycharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

I need to perform some custom settings for the `python` interpreter: specifically related to `pyspark`: the "interpeter" will actually be the `spark-submit` (aka `pyspark`) shell script.  The intent is to be able to **run** `pyspark` jobs within the `python console`. Running within a `Run Configuration` would also be just fine: this would be an alternate approach.
 I use IJ Ultimate - which has good python support: except well maybe for this particular use case.

Let us compare to `pycharm` - and specifically an ability to customize the interpreter - including setting local, remote, or virtualenv:

[image]

The Intellij Ultimate seems to lack those options: instead it is pointed to the libraries for a python sdk. That will not be sufficent for the given use case:

[image]

Here is the dropdown:  notice there is no way to add a custom python interpreter.

[image]
So is there a way in Intellij to set the interpreter path?  I want to set it to `$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark`  ?

Comment: Have you added the interpreter? The support definitely exists

Comment: @cricket_007  Please clarify.  The above dialog is all that I have found: as we can see there is no means on it to specify the `$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark` binary.

Comment: "use specified interpreter" has a drop down, and you should be able to add additional ones

Comment: @cricket_007  The only options are <Project Default> and `Python 2.7.12`. *I can not add a custom entry*.  I also updated the OP.

Comment: You're in the wrong dialog window, then. Open up the Project settings and go to "Global libraries", i think, or "SDK"

Comment: @cricket_007  Those windows do not have anything for interpreters: they permit adding e.g. `pyspark.zip` to the libraries. That does not resolve the issue of requiring `spark-submit` (aka `pyspark`)  to be invoked. Only changing the interpeter achieves the required steps for python packaging performed by `spark-submit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm and IntelliJ have the exact same options to add and configure Python code.

PyCharm just makes it easier.

> Those windows do not have anything for interpreters

Pretty sure it does... You add interpreters here.

`bin/pyspark` is not an interpreter, it is a shell script. You just set the regular Python interpreter.You also need to add the Pyspark libraries. (See below)

[image]

Then, you configure the environment variables here (Run Configurations) (see those below)

[image]

---

As far as PySpark libraries go, you have to add these (use the full path, not variables)

- `$SPARK_HOME/python/`
- `$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-X.X-src.zip`

---

You also need to set these variables in the Edit Configurations window shown

- `SPARK_HOME` = path to spark
- `PYTHONPATH` = path to py4j-X.X-src.zip (also need to append the path to the current python interpreter's directory, I believe)

Ref:

- [How to link PyCharm with PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark)
- https://github.com/ybenoit/pyspark-ide-starter (it's got some French in it, but it's still readable)

And here's a video of some code running

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-P4keLaBzc

Comment: afaict: this does not address the point about `spark-submit` aka `pyspark`: *yes* it *is* a shell script: and **that** is what is needed for launching spark job.  Adding the libraries would allow the code to compile. But it does not move the needle in terms of launching a job on a spark cluster afaik.  But in any case the clear next step: *please try it out yourself*: show a tiny/simple four line `pyspark` program launched from Intellij using your approach. I'd love to be shown off target/incorrect - and with a working pyspark from IJ.

Comment: Here's another thought: no need to even invoke `spark-submit`/`pyspark`. Just set up a python "interpreter" (actually a  shell script)  `my-interpreter.py` to represent an arbitrary python launcher.   Show that running and we're done.

Comment: I've ran it fine... Using those exact steps. If you want to fire to a cluster, call `setMaster` (or whatever pyspark's alternative is). For example, here's even a github starter repo. https://github.com/ybenoit/pyspark-ide-starter

Comment: I already had in place the `SPARK_HOME` and `PYTHONPATH`  - since well before the OP made.   Are you saying that you can get `pyspark` to launch - without invoking `spark-submit` ?  Inside that script we have a call to a `jvm` program: there is no way that invoking a normal python interpreter would make that happen:  `exec "${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-submit pyspark-shell-main --name "PySparkShell" "$@"`  .  That invokes the `SparkSubmit` scala class. Although I *will* try again (already done so many times) how can launching this as  regular python program (w/o invoking SparkSubmit) work?

Comment: All I ever get when following any of those directions is `Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number`.

Comment: On my Mac, I used this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/36415945/2308683 Code runs absolutely fine.

Comment: I just added to the `run configuration`:  `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="pyspark-shell my_python_script.py"` and that *did* run.  Man this is rough.  The intent would be to run `pyspark-shell` and have it remain resident/running: that is why i'd like to have a `python console` instead of a `run configuration`

Comment: Then use Jupyter instead of IntelliJ ;)

Comment: I do use `jupyter` for some purposes but Intellij has great keyboard shortcuts and the best editor.  It is v convenient to have the source code in the top notch IJ editor on top and the run area on the bottom. Jupyter is pretty good overall but it's not a decent editor.

Comment: I believe there is a plugin to get Python Notebook functionality within IntelliJ.

Comment: ah yea i had forgotten . let's check that out. in any case i'm going to upvote / award. you've certainly put in the effort here.

Comment: Looks like there is *not* a plugin for IJ- only pycharm.  I am trying to get onboard with pycharm as an additional platform since it seems more python devs are over there.  Are you using CE or Ultimate pycharm?

Comment: I had Ultimate during undergrad, but didn't use the features. Just use CE right now.

Comment: k thx.  For IJ the ultimate is more stable than CE that is too buggy for serious use in my experience.  Cost is v low  not an issue. Sounds like the  pycharm CE were actually usable/stable.

Comment: Btw, I can open ipynb files perfectly fine in IntelliJ CE

Comment: ah!  i'd like to use IJ. I just tried out pycharm. It's a keyboardist hater: e.g. context menus do not recognize accelerator keys (e.g. typing `p` to select `Paste`) so you have to manually scroll down.  So  will try opening a nb in ij

Comment: You'll have to download the Python plugin and configure the interpreters (as shown)

Comment: oh i've been using python in IJ for long time - it's great.  just had trouble with  pyspark.   btw is there any way to hit "enter" to run a cell -like in jupyter? tell you what I'll make another cupcake question for that and you can get some more points.

Comment: I deleted the question pending more familiarity: there *is* a command vs edit mode.   If the only thing missing were keystroke to run then i can live with that.

Comment: When I do `shift-enter` on IJ python plugin on a notebook it brings up a ` Start jupyter server` dialog .. and which apparently is failing.  So i misinterpreted that behavior. The issue is the start nb server command fails .

Comment: In case you were curious here is a question on the error  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473211/non-existing-current-directory-error-when-starting-ipython-jupyter-notebook-se