# Pycharm, Jupyter Notebook, import my own source files from different directory

Tags: python, import, pycharm, jupyter

My directory structure is as follows.

```
project/
  jupyter/
    note.ipynb
  src/
    some_script.py
    another_script.py
```

The `jupyter` subdirectory contains Jupyter notebooks and the `src` subdirectory contains my `.py` files. The `src` subdirectory is marked as the sources root.

In the Jupyter notebook `note.ipynb`, if I do `import some_script`, then I get `ImportError: No module named 'some_script'`. However, `from src import some_script` works fine, but not if `some_script` also has a line `import another_script`. In my mind I'm thinking that there is a setting or switch somewhere that adds the `src` subdirectory to the `PYTHONPATH` used by the Jupyter Notebook environment by default, but I don't know how to do it, could you help?

I know that I can always use `sys.path.append` but I don't want to do that in every single Jupyter notebook I create. I know also that I can just put the `.ipynb` files and `.py` files in the same subdirectory but I don't like organising my work that way. Finally, I know I can just set the project directory as my sources root instead of the `src` subdirectory, but that would mean that I'd have to do `from src import ...` everywhere in my `.py` scripts, and obviously I don't want to do that. Is there a solution to this problem as I've described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my mind I'm thinking that there is a setting or switch somewhere that adds the src subdirectory to the `PYTHONPATH` used by the Jupyter Notebook environment by default

Yes, you can set ENV variables per kernel, but you'll need to find the place where those are stored.

You can run `jupyter kernelspec list` for that, then open up a `kernel.json` in those.

For example, this one is from my PySpark Jupyter kernel.

See the `env: { "PYTHONPATH":` variable.

```
{
  "argv": [
    "/Users/name/Library/Jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_pyspark_16/bin/run.sh",
    "--profile",
    "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "env": {
    "DEFAULT_INTERPRETER": "PySpark",
    "__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__": "",
    "__TOREE_OPTS__": "",
    "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/opt/apache-spark@1.6/libexec",
    "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/opt/apache-spark@1.6/libexec/python:/usr/local/opt/apache-spark16/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip",
    "PYTHON_EXEC": "python"
  },
  "display_name": "Apache Toree - PySpark (1.6)",
  "language": "python"
}
```

Comment: I see. So there is no "elegant" way of doing this in PyCharm, for example by checking a box or something?

Comment: I mean, you could set `PYTHONPATH` within PyCharm GUI, yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this helps but Jupyter restricts itself to looking only at files below the place it was opened in, this is as far as I know , by design to help make serving Jupyter Notebooks more secure. In multi user environments by default.