# how to combine pyspark and anaconda in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pycharm, anaconda

I am using anaconda for some libraries such pandas and I would like to parallelize some operations using pyspark. I am using pycharm IDE and I have been looking a way to get pyspark (or simply spark) features incorporated in the pycharm without loosing anaconda environment, and I haven't found it. 
I would also like to mention that I have to use pycharm IDE. Does any one has an IDE?

Comment: [How to link PyCharm with PySpark?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34685905/1560062)

Comment: @zero323 Thanks answering.  The problem with the link you provided is that if I change the environment to pyspark like they suggest, I will automatically loose the anaconda environment, and I need it too

Comment: You won't loose anything. You can use existing conda env and edit path.

Comment: @zero323 I tried it worked. I however have to give up do the python 3.6 bugs and compatibility problems. Thanks for your answer though

Comment: Yup,  Unreleased 2.1.1 / 2.2.0  are the earliest releases with Python 3.6 support: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19019