# setup pySpark on intellij

Tags: python-2.7, intellij-idea, pyspark

How to set up pySpark on intellij. Even after setting the environment variables spark_home and pythonpath, import pySpark is giving error - Import error : No module named pySpark

Comment: Have a look at `findSpark`. The problem is that PySpark isn't on sys.path by default You can address this by either symlinking pyspark into your site-packages, or adding pyspark to sys.path at runtime. findspark does the latter, see https://github.com/minrk/findspark

Comment: you can try this https://medium.com/@gauravmshah/pyspark-on-intellij-with-packages-auto-complete-5e3208504707

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark) worked for me.

There are 2 changes:

1. At the interpreter level  - add $SPARK_HOME/python path for code completion

2. For the run configuration - add $SPARK_HOME and the Py4j-*.zip to PYTHONPATH for submitting jobs

Answer (score 0):

- Go to File -> Settings
- Look for Project Structure
- Click on Add Content Root and add `$SPARK_HOME`/python

After this, your editor will look in the Spark's python directory for source files.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on edit configuration
2. Click on environment variables
3. Add these variables

   `PYTHONPATH = %SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\build;%PYTHONPATH%`

   `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS = --master local[2] pyspark-shell`

   `SPARK_HOME = <spark home path>`

   `SPARK_CONF_DIR = %SPARK_HOME\conf`

   `SPARK_LOCAL_IP = 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I followed steps as per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8AcYWQuv-M and it helped me connect successfully, with modifications as below.

- Ensuring Plugin for Python is installed (I used Python 3.9)
- Downloading Spark 3.1.1 from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html. Entering details of python and py4j paths from here.
- Setting the JAVA_HOME correctly -  lower jdk 1.8 (JDK home path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home)
- The extra additional step that I did was adding JAVA_HOME same as above as Environment Variable under Run/Debug Configurations option in IntelliJ.