# Error: Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching: (Pycharm in windows)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I am new to PYCHARM. I have configured everything properly but still facing below issue, when i try to execute simple code
`Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching:`

In project interpreters i have updated the paths for PYTHON, PY4J.zip, PYSPARK.zip and SPARK till bin (bin not included)

versions are as below:

```
Python version - 3.6.4
Spark - 2.2.1
```

Do I need to configure anything?

Comment: you need to set the SPARK_HOME in your environment path

Comment: You mean system environment ? if so should i include bin?

Comment: nope . only until spark parent directory. like SPARK_HOME=path/spark-2.2.1

Comment: Still facing the issue

Comment: can you update with what you've tried to set and how?

Comment: under system environment variables > new SPARK_HOME and the path is c/user/zo1o/download/spark

Comment: update the question with much more details. and your path seems wrong

Comment: What path you are mentioning about ? i have mentioned enough information in my post. please let me know what exactly you are looking for

Comment: I guess `c/user/zo1o/download/spark`  should be `c:\user\zo1o\download\spark`. isn;t it?

Comment: I have used proper path, still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you have configured. So you can use below code for configuration.

Here i have used winutils path for HADOOP_HOME, If you are using Hadoop please mention proper hadoop_home path.

```
import sys
import os
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "C:/Users/LZ/Spark"
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = "C:/Users/LZ/winutils"
sys.path.append("C:/Users/LZ/Spark/python")
sys.path.append("C:/Users/LZ/Spark/python/lib")
```

After implementing above code you may able to run your code in PYCHARM. Hope this helps

Comment: Its working fine. But i have to add this code for every `.Py` file right?

Comment: @Zo1o: Yes, You need to add

Comment: Previously i used to work in eclipse ide. In that i just have to specify Spark_Home,Hadoop_Home and Python paths. Cant we do the same in PYCHARM?

Comment: [please reffer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark?rq=1)