# Adding External libraries to Pycharm's community Edition

Tags: pycharm

I am trying to add pyspark libraries to the Pycharm's community edition. Can you suggest me a way to add external libraries to community version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link PyCharm with PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

Click on File, settings, project:xxx/project Interpreter, click the '+' button, type in 'pyspark, click install at the bottom of the page. I'm also using the anaconda distribution and use that as my interpreter.