# How to Set the path of manually Downloaded Spark in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have downloaded spark from:
[download link of Spark](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)

and I tried to set the path of SPARK_HOME to the downloaded Spark and python path also according to this link:
[How to link PyCharm with PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark)

but it didn't worked. Please help me with this.

Comment: Could you explain in more details, what does "didn't" work mean? Exceptions, import errors, anything else?

Comment: It's not able to load SparkSession:                                               
ImportError: cannot import name 'SparkSession' from 'pyspark.sql' (unknown location)

Comment: Can you share the code snippet. And have you installed pyspark from pypi?