# Problem in using pyspark in pycharm but noproblem in pyspark shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

I am new to pyspark. I found a simple python code in a tutorial.
when I try this code in pyspark shell, I have no problem and I see the result.

But when I copy and paste this code in a .py file and try to run it in pyCharm environment, lots of exceptions I receive!

Can anybody help me? Should I do something in pyCharm Interpreter setting or else?

Comment: What kind of problems? PyCharm doesn't load Spark libraries by default like the shell does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link PyCharm with PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark)

Comment: yes this answers! thanks