# Import PySpark packages with a regular Jupyter Notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

What is `pyspark` actually doing except importing packages properly? Is it possible to use a regular `jupyter notebook` and then import what is needed?

Comment: Nothing against `pyspark`, just trying to understand how Spark (PySpark) works.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible but can be painful. While Python alone is not an issue and all you need is to set `$SPARK_HOME`, add `$SPARK_HOME/python` (and if not accessible otherwise `$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-[VERSION]-src.zip`) PySpark script handles JVM setup as well (`--packages`, `--jars` `--conf`, etc.).

This can be handled using `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` variable or using `$SPARK_HOME/conf` (see for example [How to load jar dependenices in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33908156/1560062)).

There is an old [blog post from Cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-use-ipython-notebook-with-apache-spark/) which describes example configuration and, as far a I remember, still works.

Comment: How about if i want to send my own `py` library that has several of classes, etc?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto As usual. Either install on workers or send using PyFiles if possible. Do you experience any problems with that?

Comment: The documentation is pretty ambiguous, and I was trying to do that without any positive result in `Python` nor in `Scala`, I have to try it once again.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider creating a pySpark kernel for Jupyter - it would import pyspark packages for you.

Create file (need to create directory first; for older versions it might be located somewhere else):

```
~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json
```

with the following content:

```
{
 "display_name": "pySpark (Spark 1.6.0)",
 "language": "python",
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python2",
  "-m",
  "IPython.kernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "env": {
  "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6",
  "PYTHONPATH": "/usr/local/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/:/usr/local/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip",
  "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/usr/local/lib/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/shell.py",
  "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "pyspark-shell"
 }
}
```

Change the Spark's paths appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you haven't already created the context, what I like to is set the submit args using `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`:

```
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--driver-memory 15g --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.3.0 pyspark-shell'
```