# PySpark in jupyter notebook using spark-csv package

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter, spark-csv

I am using spark 1.6.0 in local mode. I have created ipython pyspark profile so pyspark kernel will start in jupyter notebook. All this works correctly.

I want to use this package [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) inside of jupyter notebook. I tried to edit file `~/.ipython/profile_pyspark/startup/00-pyspark-setup.py` and put `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0` after `pyspark-shell` command, without success. Still getting this error message:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
I have tried also [this solution][2] and many others...none of them worked.
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: An [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908156/how-to-load-jar-dependenices-in-ipython-notebook) does not solve my problem. That's the reason why I opened this one.

Comment: `export SPARK_OPTS='--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0'`