# Pandas dataframe to Spark dataframe "Can not merge type error"

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have csv data and created Pandas dataframe using read_csv and forcing all columns as string.
Then when I try to create Spark dataframe from the Pandas dataframe, I get the error message below.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
z=pd.read_csv("mydata.csv", dtype=str)
z.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 74044003 entries, 0 to 74044002
Data columns (total 12 columns):
primaryid       object
event_dt        object
age             object
age_cod         object
age_grp         object
sex             object
occr_country    object
drug_seq        object
drugname        object
route           object
outc_cod        object
pt              object
```

```
q= sqlContext.createDataFrame(z)
```

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 425, in createDataFrame
rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(data, schema)
 File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 341, in _createFromLocal
struct = self._inferSchemaFromList(data)
 File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 241, in _inferSchemaFromList
schema = reduce(_merge_type, map(_infer_schema, data))
 File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 862, in _merge_type
for f in a.fields]
 File "/usr/hdp/2.4.2.0-258/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 856, in _merge_type
raise TypeError("Can not merge type %s and %s" % (type(a), type(b)))
TypeError: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>
```

Here is an example. I am downloading public data and creating pandas dataframe but spark does not create spark dataframe from the pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

url ="http://www.nber.org/fda/faers/2016/demo2016q1.csv.zip"

import requests, zipfile, StringIO
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(r.content))
z.extractall()


z=pd.read_csv("demo2016q1.csv") # creates pandas dataframe

Data_Frame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(z)
```

Comment: a) why do you read data locally just to parallelize. This is anti-pattern. b) all columns being marked as `object` suggest some heterogeneous data which is not supported by Spark DataFrames.

Comment: You are right, it is not the right way to read locally but since other options failed I hoped a dataframe from pandas will be easy for spark to handle. As you said the columns are heterogenous. Is there a workaround that I can try?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Some toy sample which will illustrate what is going on there...

Comment: I have added an example code with public data.

Comment: The best solution is in
 https://cumsum.wordpress.com/2020/02/02/typeerror-field-xxx-can-not-merge-type-class-pyspark-sql-types-longtype-and-class-pyspark-sql-types-stringtype/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Long story short don't depend on schema inference. It is expensive and tricky in general. In particular some columns (for example `event_dt_num`) in your data have missing values which pushes Pandas to represent them as mixed types (string for not missing, NaN for missing values).

If you're in doubt it is better to read all data as strings and cast afterwards. If you have access to code book you should always provide schema to avoid problems and reduce overall cost.

Finally passing data from the driver is anti-pattern. You should be able to read this data directly using `csv` format (Spark 2.0.0+) or `spark-csv` library (Spark 1.6 and below):

```
df = (spark.read.format("csv").options(header="true")
    .load("/path/tp/demo2016q1.csv"))

## root
##  |-- primaryid: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- caseid: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- caseversion: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- i_f_code: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- i_f_code_num: string (nullable = true)
##   ...
##  |-- to_mfr: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- occp_cod: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- reporter_country: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- occr_country: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- occp_cod_num: string (nullable = true)
```

In this particular case adding `inferSchema="true"` option should work as well but it is still better to avoid it. You can also provide schema as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

schema = StructType.fromJson({'fields': [{'metadata': {},
   'name': 'primaryid',
   'nullable': True,
   'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'caseid', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'caseversion', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'i_f_code', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {},
   'name': 'i_f_code_num',
   'nullable': True,
   'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'event_dt', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'event_dt_num', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'mfr_dt', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'mfr_dt_num', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'init_fda_dt', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {},
   'name': 'init_fda_dt_num',
   'nullable': True,
   'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'fda_dt', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'fda_dt_num', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'rept_cod', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {},
   'name': 'rept_cod_num',
   'nullable': True,
   'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'auth_num', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'mfr_num', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'mfr_sndr', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'lit_ref', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'age', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'double'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'age_cod', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'age_grp', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'age_grp_num', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'sex', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'e_sub', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'wt', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'double'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'wt_cod', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'rept_dt', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'integer'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'rept_dt_num', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'to_mfr', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'occp_cod', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {},
   'name': 'reporter_country',
   'nullable': True,
   'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {}, 'name': 'occr_country', 'nullable': True, 'type': 'string'},
  {'metadata': {},
   'name': 'occp_cod_num',
   'nullable': True,
   'type': 'integer'}],
 'type': 'struct'})
```

directly to the reader:

```
(spark.read.schema(schema).format("csv").options(header="true")
    .load("/path/to/demo2016q1.csv"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. Actually, I switched to Pandas because I could not successfully add the spark-csv library to Jupyter. I am using HDP 2.4 (Spark 1.6) and I installed Jupyter. I downloaded spark-csv and commons-csv and specified the path to these jars in the Jupyter notebook starter but when I try to read csv data it fails saying that it could not get the libraries. Now, I tried from the spark shell and everything is Ok. Have you ever used the spark-csv library in Jupyter (ipython) notebook?

Comment: Sure, this methods should work just fine http://stackoverflow.com/a/35762809/1560062

Comment: It works like charm! Thank you a million. I tried many other options and spent a lot of time. The link you provided helped me to complete it in minutes.

Comment: great answer. i spent hours to find this perfect one

Answer (score 4):

You could also try to

1. import your data as a pandas dataframe
2. replace the Nans for a string
3. try now to change the pandas df into spark df

```
import numpy as np

df["column"].iloc[np.where(df["column"].isna() == True[0])] = "Nan values"
```

Comment: Please fix the parenthesis, also would be useful to call numpy import (or use pandas where)

Comment: Interesting alternative, but just use `df["column"] = df["column"].fillna("Nan values")`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
z = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv", dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)
```

Comment: This long-resolved question was about converting a pandas df to spark. It does not look like you are addressing this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:
`df = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv", dtype=str, keep_default_na=False) print(df) df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df) df1.show(truncate=False)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).