# TypeError: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, databricks

I have a data frame df. I want to convert it to spark data frame. So I wrote it in databricks with runtime version 7

```
df_s=spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

But I'm getting error message as

```
TypeError: value of map value of map field elements: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'>
```

I don't have any field name `map value` in my data frame. Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please provide more information on your dataframe `df`

Comment: You may have columns with mixed type in your pandas dataframe. FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794522/pandas-dataframe-to-spark-dataframe-can-not-merge-type-error

Comment: @mck, thanks for pointing the link. But there it's implementing during csv reading steps. How can I implement same logic in data frame, after importing csv?

Comment: you should read the csv directly using spark `spark.read.csv(...)` rather than reading it using pandas and converting the pandas dataframe into spark dataframe.