# modify jupyter kernel to add cassandra connection in spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Kernel working with PySpark.

```sh
> cat kernel.json
{"argv":["python","-m","sparkmagic.kernels.pysparkkernel.pysparkkernel", "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name":"PySpark"
}
```

I want to modify this kernel to add a connection to cassandra. In script mode, I type :

```sh
pyspark \
    --packages anguenot:pyspark-cassandra:0.7.0 \
    --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=12.34.56.78 \
    --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=cassandra \
    --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=cassandra
```

**The script version works perfectly. But I would like to do the same in Jupyter.**

Where should I input these informations in my kernel ? I already tried both :

```json
{"argv":["python","-m","sparkmagic.kernels.pysparkkernel.pysparkkernel", "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name":"PySpark with Cassandra",
 "spark.jars.packages": "anguenot:pyspark-cassandra:0.7.0",
 "spark.cassandra.connection.host": "12.34.56.78",
 "spark.cassandra.auth.username": "cassandra",
 "spark.cassandra.auth.password": "cassandra"
}
```

and

```json
{"argv":["python","-m","sparkmagic.kernels.pysparkkernel.pysparkkernel", "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name":"PySpark with Cassandra",
 "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--packages anguenot:pyspark-cassandra:0.7.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=12.34.56.78 --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=cassandra --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=cassandra"
}
```

None of them are working. When I execute :

```py
sqlContext.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="my_table", keyspace="my_keyspace")\
    .load()
```

I receive error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra`.

---

FYI : I am not creating the Spark session from within the notebook. The `sc` object already exists when starting the kernel.

Comment: @user8371915 the "possible dupplicate" is not answering my problem as I am not `creating the Spark session from within the notebook` as mention is the answer ...

Comment: Packages have to be included __before the session is initialized__. Where you initialize it doesn't matter and the same methods apply. Configuration option which are set after session objects has been created, won't have effect at all.

Comment: @user8371915 OK, so I tried : `
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('my_awesome')\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "anguenot:pyspark-cassandra:0.7.0")\
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "12.34.56.78")\
    .config("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra")\
    .config("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra")\
    .getOrCreate()
spark.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="my_table", keyspace="my_keyspace")\
    .load()
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.
`

Comment: `getOrCreate` will use existing `SparkContext`. You have to set the configuration, before any Spark objects are used (to be precise before JVM has been started). Personally I would just use Spark configuration and move on. Hardcoding this anywhere in the kernel seem like a bad idea.

Comment: @user8371915 That is the reason why I need to input the parameters in jupyter kernel ... because jupyter automatically initialize the SparkContext. I cannot input anything prior to that. Therefore, the answer you gave me is not what I need.

Comment: If you don't want to modify kernel and / or Spark configuration then it is just not possible. Once JVM is up, no related configuration will have an effect.

Comment: @user8371915 I never said I dont want. Im just saying I dont know how. I tried and failled, and your duplicate answer did not help.

Answer (score 0):

`spark.jars.*` options has to be configured *before*
 `SparkContext` has been initialized. After this happened, configuration will have no effect. This means you have to do one of the following:

- Modify `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` or `SPARK_CONF_DIR/spark-defaults.conf` and make sure that `SPARK_HOME` or `SPARK_CONF_DIR` are in the scope when kernel is started.
- Modify kernel initializing code (where the `SparkContext` is initialized) using the same methods as described in [Add Jar to standalone pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35762459/8371915)

I would also strongly recommend [Configuring Spark to work with Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47824131/8371915)