Writing to a delta table spark 3.5.3 delta lake 3.2.0
It seems I'm unable to write using the delta format from my spark job, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm using spark 3.5.3 and deltalake 3.2.0.
My error:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: delta. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.

My build.sbt:
name := "test"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.18"
logLevel := Level.Warn
assembly / logLevel := Level.Warn
clean / logLevel := Level.Warn

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.5.3" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.5.3" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "io.delta" %% "delta-spark" % "3.2.0"

assembly / test := {}
assemblyJarName := s"${name.value}-${version.value}.jar"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _                        => MergeStrategy.first
}


and my job:
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("test")
      .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
      .config(
        "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog",
        "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
      )
      .getOrCreate()

val df = getData(spark)

val path = "/home/user/testtable"

df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(path)

spark.stop()

Any thoughts? I'm looking at the delta lake quickstart, but I'm not seeing anything I'm missing. I feel like there's something obvious though.

How do you run your code?
Just in case, if you prepare fat jar with sbt assembly and then submit it via spark-submit don't forget --packages io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0.
.config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0") doesn't work. libraryDependencies += "io.delta" %% "delta-spark" % "3.2.0" in build.sbt is not enough either.
Try
cd /path_to_project/target/scala-2.12
/path_to_spark/spark-3.5.3-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-submit --packages io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0 test-0.1.jar


That was it! Do you know specifically why you need to do this? What's the difference between using --packages and spark.jars.packages or the sbt inclusion?

@William Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62106554/why-does-spark-submit-ignore-the-package-that-i-include-as-part-of-the-configura (it's about Pyspark but relevant in Scala too)

@William Basically you have to make already existing spark-submit SparkSession aware of dependencies
