# How to add Spark-csv-master in ipython jupyter notebook in windows?

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with `apache-spark` and `ipython` and trying to load csv file in notebook. but I am getting error:
 `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.load.`
 While searching I found out that by loading `spark-csv` this will be resolved. I want to know how to load spark-csv in notebook in windows, and also if someone can tell me another way to resolve this error. I have uploaded a screen shot of error.

[py4jjavaerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b29cf.png) [errorpic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPVzN.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add any new library like spark-csv in Apache Spark prebuilt version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757439/how-to-add-any-new-library-like-spark-csv-in-apache-spark-prebuilt-version)

Comment: Its not duplicate. in this particulr question you mention he asked about adding spark-csv in apache prebuilt version and i asked about adding in jupyter notebook. and i also asked about any other method to solve py4jjava error.

Comment: just add the jars or package your error will be solved its a duplicate.

Comment: ok so tell me how to add jars or package in jupyter notebook in windows? all the answer of that question you mention is not working for me...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  This is the way that I fixed. I used anaconda 3.5 jupyter notebook and Windows 10:

```
import os
import sys

SUBMIT_ARGS = "--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0 pyspark-shell"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = SUBMIT_ARGS

spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
if not spark_home:
    raise ValueError('SPARK_HOME environment variable is not set')
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'C:/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip'))

exec(open(os.path.join(spark_home, 'C:/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py')).read()) # python 3


from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('C:/spark_data/train.csv')

df.show()
```